# How to change default directory for creating new files

Tags: java, file, web-applications, netbeans

I was using the following c'tor in my java web application

```
public File(String pathname)
```

For example:
 File =new File("1.txt");
Then I get the following file in the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\bin\1.txt
```

My question: why is this the default folder when using the above c'tor and also if there is any option to change it by default for the project folder for example.

Thanks

Comment: there is no way you can set file in by JoopEggen answer then why you accepted his answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File for a relative path uses `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, the application startup directory (which almost always is a bad idea). In a web application you want to use the Servlet's `getRealPath("/1.txt")` which goes relative from the web app directory. Note not `\\` but `/`.

Comment: This is misleading.  It seems to imply that you can change the current directory by altering the `"user.dir"` system property.  That won't work.  In fact, Java doesn't provide a way change the JVM's current directory.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't given a path while creation of file, by default it is creating the file where your .Java file is resides. To prevent this, you can use,

```
File file = new File ( "C:\\1.txt" );
```

Now it is going to create 1.txt in C: drive.

You can check the [File Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html). There is no way to set default path instead you specify in in the `File()` constructor it self.

Comment: Yes I know that, but thought that there is some way to specify another "root" folder by default

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to set default path.

Answer (score 1):

> and also if there is any option to change it by default for the project folder for example.

In a servlet, you can use

```
File f = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/1.txt"));
```